Can I derive vector space-equivalent from direct sum?
Let $V$ be a vector space and $A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2$ are subspace of $V$ such that
$$A_1 \leq B_1, \ A_2 \leq B_2,\ A_1\oplus A_2 = B_1 \oplus B_2$$
Then $A_1 = B_1 , A_2 = B_2$?

What I found :
Due to the definition of direct sum, $A_1 \cap A_2 = B_1 \cap B_2 = \{ 0\}$.
And $A_1\oplus A_2 = B_1 \oplus B_2 = S$ (say), then $A_1 + A_2 = B_1 + B_2 = S$.
Comparing dimension, $\dim(A_1) \leq \dim(B_1)$ and $\dim(A_2) \leq \dim(B_2)$.
And $\dim(A_1) + \dim(A_2) = \dim(B1) + \dim(B_2)$.
Add both side I got
$$\dim(A_1) + \dim(A_2) \leq \dim(B_1) + \dim(B_2)$$
And this implies $\dim(A_1) = \dim(B_1)$ and $\dim(A_2) = \dim(B_2)$
(I am not sure about this)

But I don't know how should I keep going. I think I should use $A_1 + A_2 = B_1 + B_2 = S$ but I have no idea.
Since I am new to linear algebra and direct sum, detailed answer would be helpful.
(also verifying my attempt would be helpful to me)
Thanks for help.

I am assuming you are working with finite-dimensional vector spaces only.  You are on the right track.  Your question is ostensibly about integers $a_i, b_i$ ($i=1,2$) with the properties $a_i \leq b_i$ and $a_1+a_2 = b_1+b_2$.  You wish to prove $a_i=b_i$.  (This will finish your argument since $A_i$ is now a subspace of $B_i$ of equal dimension, hence $A_i=B_i$.)
Well, $b_1 = a_1+a_2-b_2  \leq a_1 +b_2-b_2 =a_1$ and so $a_1=b_1$.  The same applies to show $a_2=b_2$.

Thanks for help, Can different result be derived if I allow vector space can be infinite-dimension?

In the infinite-dim case it is actually false.
